# TurboGears 2.x app-layer config namespacing

Tags: paster, turbogears2

Coming from a Django background, I'm accustomed to the framework providing a configuration mechanism which is suitable (and intended) for app-layer configuration rather than framework configuration only.

The TurboGears 2.x template includes a `<app_module>.config.app_cfg` module, which can be overridden by deployment ini files; however, this is explicitly documented as being for "TG2-specific" settings, and I don't see any kind of naming convention or namespace mechanism documented which would prevent a configuration entry I come up with for my app from colliding with new settings added to other framework components in the future.

Does TurboGears 2.x provide, or does the set of accepted best practices for TG2 developers (Paste, etc) include, any mechanism for managing configuration for applications built on TG2, not specific to TG2 itself? If reusing the TG2 configuration mechanism is conventional, is there any accepted practice for configuration namespace management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `config` in TurboGears2 supports complex structures, for example you can declare the options for your application inside `myapp.option1` `myapp.option2` and so on. They will be accessible inside your application both as `tg.config['myapp.option1']` and `tg.config.myapp.option1`.

This way you will avoid collisions.

Options can be set both in your `development.ini`and `config.app_cfg`.

For example, if you put inside your `app_cfg`

```
base_config['myapp.option1'] = 'FOOBAR'
```

the FOOBAR string will be accessible from `tg.config.myapp.option1`

Pay attention that `base_config` object overwrites options loaded from the **.ini** configuration file.